# Is $\mathbb{Q}(z,\dots,z^{n-1})$ the splitting field of some polynomial $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, where $z$ is a primitive root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field, primitive-roots

Is $\mathbb{Q}(z,...z^{n-1})$ the splitting field of some polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, where $z$ is a primitive root of unity?

I know that if $n\ge 1$ and $k$ is a field, and $f(x)=x^n-1\in k[x]$, then there is an extension $K/k$ over which $f(x)$ splits. But I am not sure if this is even relevant to the question at hand.

Thanks.

Comment: First, $\mathbb{Q}(z,\ldots,z^{n-1})=\mathbb{Q}(z)$ because every $z^i$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}(z)$. Second, yes, it is the splitting field of $x^n-1$ (or $x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1$) because the latter has all its roots there and the field is generated by one of its roots, $z$.

Comment: in general $k(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ is the splitting field of some polynomial of $k[x]$ whenever $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are algebraic over $k$.

Comment: @user1952009: That's only true if the extension is normal.

Comment: @carmichael561 : can you explain ? at first I wrote with $\mathbb{Q}$, but then I replaced by $k$ by thinking "it is true if $k$ is a commutative field" and if someone wants to add some details I'll learn something.

Comment: @user1952009: If $L/K$ is a finite (separable for simplicity) extension of fields, then $L$ is a splitting field of a polynomial in $K[X]$ precisely when $L$ is a normal extension of $K$.

Comment: @carmichael561 :  so what I wrote is basically completely false in general, wiki gives the example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ that wouldn't be the splitting field of any polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: @user1952009: Exactly.

Comment: @carmichael561 : thank you, without this example, this seems non-trivial to me (that there is a difference between $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $a$), and it is not often discussed on the forum.

Comment: It's quite clear when you realize that an irreducible polynomial may have both real and complex roots, so adjoining one of the real roots gets you none of the complex ones.